# Audio loading library android

Tags: android, audio-streaming

Which library is useful to load audio or video file from API and play to the application? I tried glide for the image. But no idea about audio or video. (I want to fetch the image and file name to the recycle view after click operation file will play to the next activity.) A short guideline with library name is very helpful.

Comment: please google it, exoplayer (used by YouTube) is a popular library that will fulfill above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Android has MediaPlayer to load and play Audio and Video from URL. you can setDataSource as URL.

refer [this answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32284355/9792247)

Answer (score 0):

You have Two approach one of them is using official Library (Media Player Library for music and VideoView for video) and other approach is using custom library I suggest you to using ExoPlayer Library for playing music and video

you can use following link:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer